# Does civibuild work?

Tags: civibuild

Brand new Ubuntu 20.04 VM. A `--full` install of the latest and greatest buildkit, configured per the developer guide. `civibuild create dmaster` is the only build that's successfully executed so far. It installed Drupal 7.90-dev. I don't know which version of Civi; it was initially disabled and when I enabled the module, it said I had to configure it first. Clicking the link to configure gives `Error: Class 'Civi\Setup' not found in civicrm_setup_page()`. End of that, don't matter because I'm looking for a current build anyway.

The first build I attempted after configuring buildkit was `civibuild create d9civi545 --type drupal9-clean --civi-ver 5.45 --url http://d9civi545.localhost`. It produced about 40KB of output and I believe it got pretty far in the process, but ultimately died with an `implode(): Invalid arguments passed`. It did not get far enough along to create a database or vhost config.

After that I tried again with Civi 5.46 instead, and then tried `civibuild create d9-master`. Those failed very quickly, with various dependencies failing to install, then exiting when it couldn't delete some file.

So what do you think I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What php version? If the OS is latest-greatest it might be using an unsupported php version. FYI dmaster means the latest dev code, which is fine for a dev install so I don't think that would be related to the problem.

Comment: The buildkit install script installed everything in this VM, including Apache, MySQL, and PHP. Shouldn't be a version incompatibility.